# Compilation Failed. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. retrieve the loaderexceptions

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, exception

I have been facing loader exception quite for a while which after trying many solutions I'm still unable to fix. Here is my problem, when I build one of my project in a solution in Visual studio 2010, I get below error

'***Compilation Failed. Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the Loaderexceptions property for more information.***'

Few of what I tried:
1. I checkedOut the new codebase from the repository to make sure my code changes or any property changes has nothing to cause this exception. My team mates have them executing without any build errors. 
2. Checked for the required dll's in the output directory
3. Checked if there is any version mismatch between .Net and the dll's being compiled.
4. Set copy local attribute to true to all the reference in the project.
5. Uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio 2010
6. Restarted my PC
7. I finally used 'Assembly Binding log viewer' to see if its failing to load any dll's and it gave  different logs each time I compiled the project. Sample logs below:

***Assembly Binder Log Entry  (7/19/2015 @ 9:10:41 PM) 

 
The operation failed.

Bind result: hr = 0x80070002. The system cannot find the file specified.

 
Assembly manager loaded from:  
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\clr.dll

Running under executable  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.exe

--- A detailed error log follows. 

 
=== Pre-bind state information ===

LOG: DisplayName = XXX.Common.Qty, Version=1.0.8.407, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, processorArchitecture=AMD64

 (Fully-specified)

LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/

LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL

LOG: Cache Base = NULL

LOG: AppName = Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.exe

Calling assembly : (Unknown).

===

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.

LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Workflow.Compiler.exe.Config

LOG: Using host configuration file: 

LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.

LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/XXX.Common.Qty.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/XXX.Common.Qty /XXX.Common.Qty.DLL.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/XXX.Common.Qty.EXE.

LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/XXX.Common.Qty /XXX.Common.Qty.EXE.

LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.***

But, I'm able to see this XXX.Common.Qty.dll in the output directory and so I'm not sure why this message is thrown.

**Note:** All this issue started occurring after I had my PC crash and this exception started happening in the new PC. By any means, is there a chance that a new PC could throw such errors due to some wrong configurations ?

I would highly appreciate anyone who could share your experience solving this problem. This problem has been big time affecting me from doing any work.

Thanks much for taking time to read this issue.

**NOTE:** I found something that was weird. My codebase lies in D drive inside a folder called as automation_framework, unfortunately this same folder is getting created in V drive. When I delete, create, rename them in D drive, same thing happens in V drive. I think there is a symbolic link created between them which could be the cause for the exceptions. Now, I'm trying to get rid of this mapping between these 2 drives but unsure how I can do without loss of data in D drive. Please, let me know of how I can remove them.

Also, when I opened the solution in V: drive, i see some of the projects are unavailable(which is the same project i was trying to compile from D drive) and it throws the below error which seems to be the major cause, there is this process being created in the background which seems to have locked my sandbox and I'm unable to get rid of this.

**V:\SampleProj\WF\Manualtasks\WF.Manualtasks.csproj : error  : Starting the SCM daemon (C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational Team Concert Client for Microsoft Visual Studio IDE\3rd Party\scmtools\eclipse\scm.exe) on V:\ returned error: **Sandbox(es) locked by an unknown process.**
**Problem running 'daemon start':**
**Failed to lock all sandboxes. Could not lock "Status INFO: com.ibm.team.filesystem.client code=0 Unable to lock file V:.jazz5.jazzlock null"**.**

Comment: rebuild the solution once..and check

Comment: Thanks @utility ! I did try them but it failed me again

Comment: are you able to open all forms?..there may be some tools used by you that got disappeared when system got crashed i assume

Comment: @maybe referenced dll path is not valid!! please before check dll path clean and rebuild solution.

Comment: your app tries to load this XXX.Common.Qty.dll with processorArchitecture=AMD64. Maybe something mixed with platform target?

Comment: @alireza : I did check their path but while doing so, I found something that was weird. My codebase lies in D drive inside a folder called as automation_framework, unfortunately this same folder is getting created in V drive. When I delete, create, rename them in D drive, same thing happens in V drive. I think there is a symbolic link created between them which could be the cause for the exceptions. Now, I'm trying to get rid of this mapping between these 2 drives but unsure how I can do without loss of data in D drive. Please, let me know of how I can remove them.